# How to re-request photo access in iOS5?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, alassetslibrary

If user denied app's photo access, I know that it can be checked by `[ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus]` in iOS6, and reopen it in `Settings->Privacy`.

But how to check and reopen it in iOS5?

And is it possible re-request photo access?

Special thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are talking about the request the user sees for allowing the application to use their location. I'm sorry to say that there's not much you can do apart from detecting that they have denied the request and informing them what they are missing out on and giving instructions on how to go into Settings and change the setting manually.

You can test if the user has denied the location request using:

```
[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied
```

there are other cases to check for as well... Best to read the documentation.

Comment: this is really amazing answer this is what i need ... it reduces more work to me... thanx...

Answer (score 3):

Under iOS 5, a user can't deny access to their photos. There is nothing to request or re-request. Same for the address book, calendar, and reminders. All of this only applies to iOS 6.

Comment: Wrong. :) Usually photos are geolocated and you'll be prompt for  localization data when trying to access your photos.

Comment: It appears that if location services are denied for an app or the device, there is no access to the assets library. This is too bad since the UIImagePickerController can still be used in such cases, just not direct access to the assets library.